# Texture Painting Problem

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I've been trying to resolve this problem for the past 3 days, I searched a lot in the web but didn't find anything like my problem, only with small objects or related problems but none like this.

I have a cartoon landscape that I am trying to put texture with texture painting. The texture I am using has 1024x1024 size, but not matter what I do the result is nerver good.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

The first image shows a plane with 300x300 size and a 1024x1024 UV image. I simply created a material, put a texture and increase the size to 100 in the mapping part on the texture panel, and the result is what I want

But the second image shows another plane with the same size object and the same UV size, but this time I tried to paint the same image texture that I use in the first, but the result is always blurred or pixelated.

What can I do for the painting result to appear the same as the other?

I need paint the texture to put other textures like grass and other rock types. I will use this landscape in Unity so need to be simple, cant be a large 8192x8192 texture.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some more details, like your mesh objects, modifier stacks, and UV layout

Comment: Hi Duarte Farrajota Ramos, the scene have only 2 default planes scaled to 300x300 (units) no modifiers, and the uv is just the unwarped plane.. I just created 2 planes, in one I created a material and put the texture, and the other I tryed to paint  the texture..

Comment: @BryanJonson Could you upload blend file? I can try to fiddle with it and check what's wrong. Don't forget to pack texture - File > External Data > Pack all into .blend file.

Comment: Hi LukeD, I have not the same file, but this have the same problem.. te texture painting is only good big, and I need the texture smaller.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/z69i5vyyfh2tp34/TEXTURE%20PAINT%20PROBLEM.blend1?dl=0 hope the file helps. thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, textures are not packed in your file so we can't reproduce your issue (use File/External Data/Automatically pack). But anyway, the problem is surely because the painted part is very small regarding to the brush texture and the terrain's size.

Comment: Hi lemon, sorry about the mistake, never added external file, in this link I do like you say and hope the file is there.. in this file I need the right plane stay with the same quality the left.. I the both planes have the same configuration, so I dont find why only the painted is with low quality.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/261z8ouc2z6hs0v/TEXTURE%20PAINT%20PROBLEM.blend?dl=0
thanks!

Comment: anyone that can help me please?

Comment: Hi, looking in the tutorials I found 1 that help, I made a splatmap and replace the color for textures in nodes, but now I need to bake the textures in to one png image, but all tutorials are about cycles or other things.. can anyone help to only bake this? the project are on the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv5ipxk05k5ilq4/TEXTURE%20BAKE.blend?dl=0